# What's the best way to ask a user for an API Key when setting up a Slack App?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Just looking for some general advice here.

I want to build a Slack app and publish it publicly to the Slack App Directory, for anyone to use. The basics of the app are:

- When you paste a link to a specific domain in a Slack message, a bot will fetch additional information about that link from a Rest API my company built.

The roadblock I'm running into is that our Rest API uses Basic Auth for authentication, and I can't figure how or where in the Slack App setup flow to ask the user to enter their API key.

Does anyone have any advice on how to ask for user input when setting up a Slack app, so that the user can enter their API Key for our REST API?

Thanks!

Comment: Couple questions: 1) Will there be one API key used for all users, or an individual API key for each user? 2) Why do you want to publish your app to the App Directory if it can only be used by people from your corporation?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I will assume that the API key is individual to each user.

I would suggest to ask the API key as part of the installation process for your Slack app on your website and then store the connection between Slack user ID and API key as part of the installation process. It is in fact possible to have individual installations of the same Slack app to a workspace for each user. This is called "configurations" (e.g. the Twitter app for Slack is using this feature).

This requires each user who want to use the app to go through the installation process and also all users need to have permissions to install this particular Slack app (which can be configured by admin).